# Why is there a minimum size on TIPS trades for retail?

Tags: treasuries

I was buying TIPS in a personal account and there was a minimum size for each offer. The min face value was often 75k.

This seems counterintuitive to me as smaller trade sizes would leave more edge for a market maker after accounting for impact. It doesn't seem like a min size would result in fewer odd lots as I could still increment up by 1000 dollars face value.

Comment: Is this so different from most USD-denominated bonds out there?

Comment: I don't know if there is anything special about TIPS. I have only ever tried to buy TIPS so I was just trying to use TIPS as an example of something with a min size. Should I edit my question to be about USD-denominated bonds in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSRB published an interesting study about the history and the reasons behind the minimum *municipal* bond sizes https://www.msrb.org/sites/default/files/MSRB-Minimum-Denominations-of-Municipal-Securities.pdf

> Municipal securities issuers establish minimum denominations for bonds at issuance to help target the sale to an appropriate category of investors or reduce administrative costs, among other reasons...

> The adoption by issuers of a \$5,000 minimum denomination requirement appears to have developed as a market convention dating to at least the 1970s in part to reduce operational burdens that then occurred at the time of issuance (i.e., the operational burden of signing each municipal bond to be issued), and these operational burdens no longer exist because certificates for each bondholder are no longer routinely issued.

followed by a discussion of some problems associated with \$100,000 minimum size.

If you visit https://www.ginniemae.gov/about_us/what_we_do/pages/programs_products.aspx and click to expand "Ginnie Mae I vs Ginnie Mae II", it shows Minimum Certificate Size  equal to \$25,000.

Perhaps some bond issuers just don't want to face lots of bondholders with relatively small positions.

For corporate bonds, the minimum size is typically 2 bonds, i.e. \$2,000.